# Refresh Javascript to get new values from Flask

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, jinja2

I need to `autorefresh` the `load` function below so that I don't have to manually refresh the whole page and still gets the new value for `my_value`.  And if I reload the page, the chart starts over which I do not want.

I thought this returns different values every 5 second but only returns the same value every 5 second.

How do I refresh this script and updates its value every 5 second?

Could anybody tell me why this is not updating the data?

Could anybody tell me why this is not updating the data?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });
    $(function() {
        var chart;
        $('#my_id').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime();
                            // var y = {{my_value}}; // Math.random() * 100;
                            // series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "/get_data",
                                data: data, // your "template" data goes here
                                success: function(my_value) {
                                    var y = my_value;
                                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                                }
                            });
                        }, 5000);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

And here's the Flask script:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=host,
                       user=username,
                       passwd=password,
                       db=database,
                       port=port)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    request.args.get('key', '')
    df = sqlio.read_sql(qry1, conn)
    value = df['count'][0]
    return render_template('index.html', my_value=value)

@app.route('/get_data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    df = sqlio.read_sql(qry1, conn)
    value = df['count'][0]
    return value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        port=1114,
        host='0.0.0.0'
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an ajax call to get the data:

```
var x = (new Date()).getTime();
// get data from python script
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/get_data",
  data: data, // your "template" data goes here
  success: function(my_value) {
     var y = my_value;
     series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
  }
});
```

And in your server make Flask get the data:

```
@app.route('/get_data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    df = sqlio.read_sql(query, conn)
    value = df['my_column'][0]
    return value
```

Comment: But I need to use `template`. How would you use template to pass the data to this ajax call? Thanks a lot!

Comment: And I have `setInterval` and do I still need this? Trying to make it work but not

Comment: Yeah, you need it if you want to keep updating

Comment: So I tried this but still not updating. Could you look at my edit?

Comment: I get `405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: Thanks a million. But what do you mean by `"template" data goes here`?

Comment: I am trying to find out where to put `{{my_value}}` from template

Comment: Actually, I think it would be better if you created a new route just for retrieving new data to render.

Comment: Ok but I am very new to this. So just trying  to make this work and make it better. How would you do? `function(my_value) {` does not get any value from `render_template`. Somehow I need to be able to pass the value from my script to `function(my_value) {` but not passing it right now.

Comment: See my edits. So you render template once, then use ajax to fetch new data.  In you flask server, create a new function just for fetching and returning the new data

Comment: THanks a lot. Really appreciate it. But still somehow I need to render template to get the value and do this `render_template('index.html', session_value=get_data())` and not working for `index()`.Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, keep the `index()` as you had before

Comment: Ok but still you don't seem to pass any data to `template` like `{{my_value}}` then how do this get the value from my python script to get the results from query?>

Comment: It's not adding any data :(

Comment: That is what ajax is for. No need for the statement `var my_value = {{my_value}};`

Comment: I see. I updated the posting again and still not work. Would greatly appreciate it if you can check. I use the same code of yours but still not updating. The graph not moving. Seems like I am not getting any newly returned values from Python

Comment: Try removing `data: data, // your "template" data goes here`

Comment: Still not updating... :(

Comment: It calls `get_data()` only once. So it returns only one value.

Comment: If you go to `/get_value` in browser, do you see your new data?

Comment: I get this `TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable` but does this matter? I get one first value correctly

Comment: And do I need to connect to `/get_data` ?

Comment: It means that you need to fix `get_data()` function.  It should contain the new data that you want to display.

Comment: Thanks. That means I need to pass new values to `get_data()` but it is called only once so keeps getting the same value not updating it. Is there anyway that I can call `get_data` several times for realtime data?

Comment: If you refresh the browser, you should see new data, right?

Comment: Then the javascript will keep calling `get_data`

Comment: Thanks but is there anyway that I can do this without `reload` that was my whole point

Comment: By using ajax, you don't need to refresh the entire page.  It makes an asyc call to your server, fetches the data, and should add a new datapoint.

Comment: I am getting TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable

Comment: Seems like keep getting the data but errors after first value